# TSQL query to delete all duplicate records but one

Tags: t-sql, sybase, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete duplicate records in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317433/delete-duplicate-records-in-sql-server)

I have a table in which unique records are denoted by a composite key, such as (`COL_A`, `COL_B`).

I have checked and confirmed that I have duplicate rows in my table by using the following query:

```
select COL_A, COL_B, COUNT(*)
from MY_TABLE
group by COL_A, COL_B
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc
```

Now, I would like to remove all duplicate records but keep only one.

Could someone please shed some light on how to achieve this with 2 columns?

**EDIT:** 
Assume the table only has `COL_A` and `COL_B`

Comment: Are the rest of the columns the same?  How do you decide which you want to keep?

Comment: @FionaT, In this case, I don't care which one I keep as long as I keep one. This is because they all have the same (COL_A, COL_B) pair. For simplicity's sake, there are only COL_A and COL_B.

Comment: If you don't have another field (hopefully a key field), then your delete statement will delete all records.  You have to have another field to differentiate the records.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317433/delete-duplicate-records-in-sql-server  Come on all I did was search SO for TSQL delete duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st solution**, 
It is flexible, because you can add more columns than `COL_A` and `COL_B` :

```
-- create table with identity filed
-- using idenity we can decide which row we can delete
create table MY_TABLE_COPY
(
  id int identity,
  COL_A varchar(30), 
  COL_B  varchar(30)
  /*
     other columns
  */
)
go
-- copy data
insert into MY_TABLE_COPY (COL_A,COL_B/*other columns*/)
select COL_A, COL_B /*other columns*/
from MY_TABLE
group by COL_A, COL_B
having count(*) > 1
-- delete data from  MY_TABLE
-- only duplicates (!)
delete MY_TABLE
from MY_TABLE_COPY c, MY_TABLE t
where c.COL_A=t.COL_A 
and c.COL_B=t.COL_B
go
-- copy data without duplicates
insert into MY_TABLE (COL_A, COL_B /*other columns*/)
select t.COL_A, t.COL_B /*other columns*/
from MY_TABLE_COPY t
where t.id = (
               select max(id) 
               from MY_TABLE_COPY c  
               where t.COL_A = c.COL_A
               and  t.COL_B = c.COL_B
             ) 
go
```

**2nd solution**
If you have really two columns in MY_TABLE you can use:

```
-- create table and copy data
select distinct COL_A, COL_B
into MY_TABLE_COPY
from MY_TABLE
-- delete data from  MY_TABLE 
-- only duplicates (!)
delete MY_TABLE
from MY_TABLE_COPY c, MY_TABLE t
where c.COL_A=t.COL_A 
and c.COL_B=t.COL_B
go
-- copy data without duplicates
insert into MY_TABLE
select t.COL_A, t.COL_B
from MY_TABLE_COPY t
go
```

Comment: You could have just used a SELECT DISTINCT on your INSERT into MY_TABLE_COPY.  Then you wouldn't need the where clause with the subquery when reinserting them.  Up vote for working around the lack of uniqueness though.

Comment: @Data Masseur Thanks. Yes I could used a `SELECT DISTINCT`, but It will work if in MY_TABLE we have more then two columns.

Comment: @DataMasseur  I edited the post with you suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
-- Copy Current Table
SELECT * INTO #MY_TABLE_COPY FROM MY_TABLE 

-- Delte all rows from current able
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE

-- Insert only unique values, removing your duplicates
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #MY_TABLE_COPY

-- Remove Temp Table
DROP TABLE #MY_TABLE_COPY
```

That should work as long as you don't break any foreign keys when deleting rows from MY_TABLE.