# Delete field Duplicates from the Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates, sql-delete

I am writing this query to display a bunch of Names from a table filled automatically from an outside source:

```
select MAX(UN_ID) as [ID] , MAX(UN_Name) from UnavailableNames group by (UN_Name)
```

I have a lot of name duplicates, so I used **"Group by"**

I want to **delete** all the **duplicates** right after I do this select query..
(Delete where the field UN_Name is available twice, leave it once)

Any way to do this?

Comment: Might be a, heh, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317433/delete-duplicate-records-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Something likes this should work:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER( 
                  PARTITION BY UN_Name
                  ORDER BY UN_ID ASC), * 
    FROM dbo.UnavailableNames
) 
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

You basically assign an increasing "row number" within each group that shares the same "un_name".

Then you just delete all rows which have a "row number" higher than 1 and keep all the ones that appeared first.

Answer (score 2):

```
With CTE As
(
Select uid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY uname order by uid) as rownum
From yourTable

)

Delete 
From yourTable
where uid in (select uid from CTE where rownum> 1 )
```