# Deleteing double-entries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I got the problem that on one table it sometimes makes a double entry. I want to delete the doubled entry. I only want to delete a row when both values are the same than on another row. How is this possible?

My DB structure:

[image]

Example for the double entries:

[image]

Comment: What is your *table's schema*?

Comment: My table where i got the double entry is Password_Department

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317433/delete-duplicate-records-in-sql-server

Comment: The duplicate explains how to do this

Comment: Why not create a unique constraint on PasswordFK and DepartmentFK?

Comment: @DavidBrabant i saw this link already and I tried it too but it wasn't working.

Comment: @mischka this is what i got

Comment: @NiZelooer can you post the code you tried from David's link? & how it didn't work? That's the method I'd recommend too.

Comment: @GarethLyons It's okay i realized that i made it wrong. The link from David was this what i need.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using exists:

```
DELETE t0
FROM Password_Department t0
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Password_Department t1
    WHERE t0.PasswordFK = t1.PasswordFK
    AND t0.DepartmentFK = t1.DepartmentFK
    AND t0.Id > t1.Id
)
```

If you prefer the row number method -

```
delete x 
from (
   select *, 
          rn = row_number() over (partition by DepartmentFK, PasswordFK order by Id)
   from Password_Department 
) x
where rn > 1
```

After you deleted the duplicate entries, you should add a unique constraint on PasswordFK and DepartmentFK:

```
ALTER TABLE Password_Department 
ADD Constraint UC_Password_Department UNIQUE (PasswordFK , DepartmentFK)
```

Comment: I tried it but 0 rows affected

Comment: @ZoharPeled AND t0.DepartmentFK = t1.DepartmentFK surely?

Comment: Yeah, there was a couple of typos there, fixed them.