# Python3 SQLAlchemy delete duplicates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to manage a database and I'm trying to delete all rows that contain duplicates. The table has an id (primary key) and domain name.

**Example:**
ID| Domain
1  | example-1.com
2  | example-2.com
3  | example-1.com

In this case I want to delete 1 instance of example-1.com. Sometimes I will need to delete more than 1 but in general the database should not have a domain more than once and if it does, only the first row should be kept and the others should be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your model looks something like this:

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'domain_names'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    domain = sa.Column(sa.String)
```

Then you can delete the duplicates like this:

```python
# Create a query that identifies the row for each domain with the lowest id
inner_q = session.query(sa.func.min(Domain.id)).group_by(Domain.domain)
aliased = sa.alias(inner_q)
# Select the rows that do not match the subquery
q = session.query(Domain).filter(~Domain.id.in_(aliased))

# Delete the unmatched rows (SQLAlchemy generates a single DELETE statement from this loop)
for domain in q:
    session.delete(domain)
session.commit()

# Show remaining rows
for domain in session.query(Domain):
    print(domain)
print()
```

If you are not using the ORM, the core equivalent is:

```
meta = sa.MetaData()
domains = sa.Table('domain_names', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

inner_q = sa.select([sa.func.min(domains.c.id)]).group_by(domains.c.domain)
aliased = sa.alias(inner_q)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(domains.delete().where(~domains.c.id.in_(aliased)))
```

This answer is based on the SQL provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3317575/5320906).  There are other ways of deleting duplicates, which you can see in the other answers on the link, or by googling "sql delete duplicates" or similar.

Comment: What is 'Base' in the class? This code is not runable. What do I miss that others didn't?

Comment: @Apostolos It's the `Base` class as used in a the standard SQLAlchemy docs.   I've edited the question to show one way of generating it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get "AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.orm' has no attribute 'declarative_base'". (My 'sqlalchemy' version is 1.3.24.)

Comment: For such an old version you'll need to use `from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base`.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb. I just upgraded 'sqlalchemy' to 2.0.23. (These guys seem to work a lot on their packages! ) Strange thing, 'sqlalchemy' was part of  the 'chatterbot' package the last version of which I installed a couple of weeks ago ...

Comment: OK, we are getting there ... I now got **"sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: statement.domain"**.  'domain' shows "(no name)" if I print it from the Domain class. How should this be set? (Note that the table from which I want to delete duplicates is already set in sqlite engine.)